# Script is not running after comment in my code using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I am trying to automate Linked in using selenium.
I want to search Journalist and wants to connect them all.
So, I wrote the code that click all the connect buttons.

but it is not working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\SUJASH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\HZ$D.705.3782\\HZ$D.705.3783\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')
time.sleep(2)

#********** LOG IN *************

username = driver.find_element("id", "session_key")
password = driver.find_element("id", "session_password")
```

#above code will find the box of Username and Password

```
username.send_keys('HIDDEN_ON_SOF')
password.send_keys('HIDDEN_ON_SOF')
time.sleep(2)
```

#above code will enter the username and Password

```
submit = driver.find_element("xpath", "//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

#above code will click the submit button
#*********** SEARCH ***********

```
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?heroEntityKey=urn%3Ali%3Aautocomplete%3A1975299068&keywords=entertainment%20journalist&origin=CLUSTER_EXPANSION&sid=uv!')
time.sleep(5)
```

'''above code has link of my search that I want to do, I want to search Entertainment journalist, so I searched Entertainmnet journalist and copy the link and pasted it here'''

```
#************ from here script is not working ****************************

all_buttons = driver.find_elements("tag_name", "button")
connect_buttons = [btn for btn in all_buttons if btn.text == "Connect"]

for btn in connect_buttons:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)
    time.sleep(2)
    send = driver.find_element("xpath" , "//button[@aria-label='Send now']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", send)
    close = driver.find_element("xpath" , "//button[@aria-label='Dismiss']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close)
    time.sleep(2)
```

''' Above code is not working, I want to click on all the connect buttons but code is not working after the comment *** from here script is not working *** '''

Comment: At which line are you exactly stuck? Update the question with the manual steps you are trying to automate.

Comment: Okay Done, Please check once.

Comment: What are the values of `all_buttons` and `connect_buttons`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using `time.sleep` to wait for LinkedIn to respond, which is always a little risky. Better to write some code that waits until the action is complete.

But, if you're going to use `time.sleep`, then you're missing a sleep between clicking send and clicking close. That could mess up your loop.